# Asp.net core navigation property always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

When I try to access the Author property on my Comment class, it is always null. I've tried using Include() on my query and also installing the lazy loading proxies to no avail. I'm using the latest versions of Asp.net core with .NET 5.
Here's my Comment class:

```
public class Comment {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual int PostReplyToId { get; set; }
    public virtual Post PostReplyTo { get; set; }

    public int? ReplyToId { get; set; }
    public virtual Comment ReplyTo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Replies { get; set; }

    public virtual string AuthorId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Author { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime TimePosted { get; set; }

    public virtual string Content { get; set; }

    public virtual bool Visible { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string CommentInvalid { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my ApplicationUser class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser {
    [ForeignKey("AuthorId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Post> PostsAuthored { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AuthorId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> CommentsAuthored { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the part of my view where I access the comment's Author property (I get a NullReferenceException here because comment.Author is null):

```
<div>
    <h4>Comments</h4>
    <p><a href="#" class="CommentReplyButton" data-commentId="null">Create a comment</a></p>
    @foreach (Comment comment in (List<Comment>)ViewBag.Comments) {
        if (comment.ReplyToId == null) {
            <div class="media" id="@("Comment" + comment.Id)">
                <a href="#"><img class="mr-3" src="~/images/pfp.png" alt="@comment.Author.Id's Profile Picture" /></a> <!-- NullReferenceException here -->
```

The query I use to set ViewBag.Comments is this (I don't think the Include is necessary as I had the same issue without it):

```
List<Comment> comments = (from comment in _context.Comment.Include(e => e.Author)
                          where comment.PostReplyToId == post.Id
                          select comment).ToList();

ViewBag.Comments = comments;
```

I ran Serge's query and the same thing happened. Here's what visual studio says comment is equal to (ViewBag.Comments is just a 1 element long list)
[Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXPSF.png)
I know that comment is definitely not null because I can successfully get the Id from the line above. I've checked the database and I know that the AuthorId is correctly set in the comment and that the comment's AuthorId field is set correctly. I know the ApplicationUser it should point to exists because it's in the database and I can log on as it.
Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Which queries in particular did you try?

Comment: @abdusco I've updated my question to have the query I use in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted my entire database and remigrated everything and it fixed it. I guess I corrupted my database somehow. I deleted the entire database from my server, deleted all the migrations, then made a new one and updated the database. It isn't optimal because I lost all my data, but it works now. Thanks for the help @Serge.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need so many virtual properties in Comment class. And try to fix navigation properies of Author. It should work

```
public class Comment {
    [Key]
    public  int Id { get; set; }

    public  int PostReplyToId { get; set; }
    public virtual Post PostReplyTo { get; set; }

    public int? ReplyToId { get; set; }
    public virtual Comment ReplyTo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Replies { get; set; }

    public  string  AuthorId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(AuthorId ))]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(ApplicationUser.CommentsAuthored))]
    public virtual ApplicationUser Author { get; set; }

    public DateTime TimePosted { get; set; }

    public  string Content { get; set; }

    public bool Visible { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string CommentInvalid { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser {

   .....

   [InverseProperty(nameof(Comment.Author))]
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> CommentsAuthored { get; set; }
}
```

and fix your query

```
var comments= _context.Comment.Include(e => e.Author)
                          .Where ( c=> c.PostReplyToId == post.Id)
                          .ToList();
```

or just for debugging try this

```
var comments = (from c in _context.Comment
                 join a in  context.Author on c.AuthorId equals a.Id
                  where c.PostReplyToId == post.Id
                  select new { comments=c, Author=a}).ToList();
```

Comment: It will not work.  You have to add navigation properties and make db migration. Only after this.

Comment: What do you mean by add navigation properties? I used your code and made a database migration but up and down were empty. I've updated my query to the one you suggested but there's been no change in behaviour.

Comment: Are you sure that you  have  none empty string AuthorId   in the record where c.PostReplyToId == post.Id? Something tells me that AuthorId is integer or long

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I appreciate you taking the time to help me. I've only got 1 comment and 1 user on my test website. I've checked on SSMS and my comment's author id definitely matches my user's entry in the user's table. I can put the database entries in the question if you think it would be helpful.

Comment: My question was are you sure that IdentityUser  Id is  a string type?

Comment: The IdentityUser Id is a GUID but I think it's stored as a string. I put a breakpoint right before the exception and AuthorId is correctly set to "bd9f04dd-967a-40bd-8250-365f3c602577".

Comment: What the exception? Why you didn' t  mention it before? And it doensnt matter how it is set here you have to change it to Guid.  What type it is the database and how  you can  keep foreign keys if it is a different type. This maybe a problem.

Comment: The exception is just a Null pointer exception, since I try to access Author.Id but Author is null. I labelled it in the cshtml code but it looks like I forgot to mention it in the question. Sorry, this is the first time I've had to ask a question here. I'm using SQL Server 2019. In a different project I was storing guids as strings and it was working fine, and I'm fairly sure I set this project up the same, but I might have messed something up. Once again thanks for helping me out. I've been researching this issue since around 2pm and it's really been bothering me.

Comment: I've just tried switching the string to a Guid and it says: The relationship from 'Comment.Author' to 'IdentityUser.CommentsAuthored' with foreign key properties {'AuthorId' : Guid} cannot target the primary key {'Id' : string} because it is not compatible.

Comment: @AgentD1 I think it  is because your db table still have a string key or maybe you have some fluent apis. You have to migrate. And don't forget about PostsAuthored  too.

Comment: I just updated my Comment code to match yours and added the InverseProperty attribute to PostsAuthored (as well as updating Post to use a Guid too) but I am now unable to add a migration. It says that: "The relationship from 'Comment.Author' to 'IdentityUser.CommentsAuthored' with foreign key properties {'AuthorId' : Guid} cannot target the primary key {'Id' : string} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship". I checked my database and the Id column of AspNetUsers is Id (PK, nvarchar(450), not null).

Comment: I am sorry but I can not see your db. You told me that key is a Guid. What class AspNetUsers  mapped to? And how do you create it? Do you use guid as a string?

Comment: I posted a full query. Try it just for debugging and see what happens

Comment: The key is in Guid format but I think it's stored as a string. I'm pretty new to asp.net core but the asp.net core identity system created the AspNetUsers table in the db. The AspNetUsers table is mapped to the IdentityUser class which I override and set as the default identity class with `services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()`. Sorry if I haven't been that helpful. I've only been using Asp.net core for a week or so and I don't have any prior database experience beyond simple select and insert. Let me know if you need to see some of my code and I'll append it to the answer.

Comment: I ran your full query. The same thing happened. I updated my answer with a screenshot of what the returned Comment looks like.